# best speed trigger/statements/transaction

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is a general sqlite question and specifically as implemented on Android.

Which offers the best peformance if a deletion on one table would require deletions on another?  This can be accomplished three ways that I see:

- To use a trigger
- DELETE statements
- A Transaction wrapping the DELETEs

Hope I've phrased it correctly, I can muck around in sql but I might not express myself properly.

Comment: Consider also [foreign key actions](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only real way to answer a question like this is to build a test case, and try it.

There are many things that can affect the execution time of a statement, and when you start adding things like triggers and transactions, the number of variables grows even more.

Write a simple test case, specifically for your application, and see which works faster for you.

Also, be wary of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).